# What is the difference between 'code readability' and 'language conventions' used within a community?

Tags: python

When I'm looking at questions asked on sites like stackoverflow on how to make a particular piece of code "more pythonic" there are usually suggestions offered to use complex list comprehensions or generators or other python features that aren't available in, say, Java.

I am a casual Python programmer, and sometimes I can't follow what's going on without carefully unwrapping the logic in my head. Sometimes the list comprehensions are nested in ways that I'm thinking "you probably should just write it out using loops".

Of course, veteran Python users probably won't have an issue with this, but I'm increasingly getting the impression that "pythonic code" is preferred over writing code that would be readable for the "average programmer" that may not be very proficient in Python.

In general, what are some guidelines and heuristics to follow when choosing between the readability of the code and following the conventions used in a specific programming language community?

Comment: For me, list comprehensions, even nested ones, are clear and concise and far more readable than loops.

Comment: Sometimes it is a sense of 'elegance'. That is a very fleeting, subjective quality. The line is fine, the balance quickly lost. At that moment it is time to use ordinary loops and be done with it.

Comment: No one should be asking how to make code "more pythonic". How about "more readable" or "more maintainable"?

Comment: @VincentPovirk Perhaps the term "pythonic" is synonymous with readable or maintainable, as I interpret the term as "writing code that conforms to python coding practice".

Comment: Who else read the title as "to be more pathetic"?

Comment: "Readability" is *always* relative to an intended audience. No code is readable to someone who is not a programmer, for example. When you write code in any language you usually expect the reader to know the language. Trying to write Python code in a way that it would be readable to Java developers who don't know Python would be crazy.

Answer (score 3):

> Sometimes the list comprehensions are nested in ways that I'm thinking "you probably should just write it out using loops".

If you would refactor the code really that way, it would most probably lead to a replacement of one evil by another. IMHO it is better not to replace too deeply nested list comprehensions by (still too deeply nested) loops. Instead, replace too deeply nested lists comprehensions by **not so deeply** nested list comprehensions. This gives you a chance to add "explaining variables" with clear names for intermediate results, and you can still think in "sets", which produces much less "noise" than loops, and is still "pythonic".

Answer (score 1):

If you're 'carefully unwrapping the logic' to make sense of a line of code, the author missed the boat on being Pythonic.  Being Pythonic isn't about using obscure language features to pack as much code as possible into a line - that's what Perl's for.  Being Pythonic is about keeping code simple, readable and efficient.

> `>>> import this`
>
> **The Zen of Python**, by Tim Peters
>
> Beautiful is better than ugly.
>
> Explicit is better than implicit.
>
> Simple is better than complex.
>
> Complex is better than complicated.
>
> Flat is better than nested.
>
> Sparse is better than dense.
>
> Readability counts.
>
> Special cases aren't special enough to break the rules.
>
> Although practicality beats purity.
>
> Errors should never pass silently.
>
> Unless explicitly silenced.
>
> In the face of ambiguity, refuse the temptation to guess.
>
> There should be one-- and preferably only one --obvious way to do it.
>
> Although that way may not be obvious at first unless you're Dutch.
>
> Now is better than never.
>
> Although never is often better than *right* now.
>
> If the implementation is hard to explain, it's a bad idea.
>
> If the implementation is easy to explain, it may be a good idea.
>
> Namespaces are one honking great idea -- let's do more of those!

Comment: I'd say Perl is more about letting the language deal with implementation details.  Just because people like to pack too much onto one line (like with Python code mentioned in the question) doesn't mean that they're writing "good" Perl.

Comment: I agree with @Izkata, Perl is all about TIMTOWDI, it doesn't have a well defined notion of what it means to be "idiomatic" perl code. The idea is to express yourself how you want to. Needless to say some people do this more poorly than others

Comment: @Izkata - just saying that, if you want to write dense, complex code and don't have an APL keyboard, Perl's the language to use, not Python.

Comment: -1, a paste of someone elses prose does not an answer make. Some details and explanations to support your position and well, explain it further than "nah.. that aint right" could make a good answer...

Comment: @jozefg: TIMTOWDI ?? means what ???

Comment: @DocBrown: Don't you think I know that? GIMF. The point is that too many people use acronyms without any consideration for the fact that others may not be familiar with them. Admittedly, not so bad in comments, but I absolutely abhor questions throwing acronyms around like there is no tomorrow and expecting everybody to either know them or google them. It's just plain lazy and inconsiderate towards the people you are asking to help you. I knew what a call to action was long before coming across the CTA acronym. Never crossed my mind that call to action is what the poster meant.

Comment: @MarjanVenema "'[There's more than one way to do it](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/There's_more_than_one_way_to_do_it)' is a Perl programming motto."

Answer (score 1):

If you can't read it, you can't debug it or maintain it.

'more Pythonic' code that you can't maintain is worthless, so for you, using the more complex features is a bad idea, no matter how elegant the answer is in terms of the language.